# Chrome console output suffering from heisenberg principle

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I discovered this strange behavior in chrome's console, and would like to know if it's intentional and, if so, what its purpose is.

An example to demonstrate:

[image: behavior hinges on whether you view this object]

Let's begin with the behavior you'd expect.  Starting from the above picture, click on the arrow next to the "Object" line to unfold it.  You can then leave it open or reclose it.  The important thing is that you unfold it once.  Now continue:

[image: observed, so not changed]

As you can see, we change the value of one of our object's keys, but the object printed out *above* it is not affected by our change, as expected.

Now clear your console and begin the experiment over.  Type out the same lines to create the object "o" and fill in its properties with the loop.  This time, however, do *not* unfold the object at the key line yet.  Instead, continue directly with the next command which changes the value of property "x7".  Only after doing so can you now go back an unfold the object at the key line.  A nice surpise will be waiting for you:

[image: future changed past]

The future has changed the past!

Comment: I could not replicate these results...

Comment: Is it unreasonable to think that interacting with the console updates the objects it displays to match their values?

Comment: @BryceHanscomb, But it doesn't do so consistently, as the first example shows.  So it's not a case of keeping everything in sync.  I believe Yuriy's answer makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No mystery here. Properties are retrieved at the time of expansion. You expanded above reference to object *after* you changed its properties below.

Comment: why is that though? performance?  because if you are using console statements to debug, this behavior can really thwart your efforts.  is there any way to turn it off?  or do I need to output object strings using JSON.parse instead?

Comment: @Jonah It's about the action not being necessary. It's the concept of a lazy object. Only does computes as needed.

Comment: @DivinusVox, right, that does make sense although as i said it really tripped up my debugging efforts tonight

Comment: @Jonah I suppose in that sense it's one of those good gotcha's to know. Lazy objects can bite you if you're not aware of them. Your best bet to save state is to serialize the object at the time it's logged, if you need to see how it mutates over time.

Comment: I'm *stunned* that this is the default behavior of any browser console. If you `console.log()` an object with less than `n` properties, it takes a snapshot. But if your object has `n+` properties, it logs a reference instead! Complete insanity!